# Django foreign key user has no attribute post_set

Tags: django, post, foreign-keys

I've got these two models.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

THIS SHOULD BE

```
def posts(self): 
        return self.user.poster.all()
```

INSTEAD OF

```
def posts(self):
        return self.user.post_set.all()

def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username



class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='poster')

def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

and I'm attempting to display all posts by a user on this html page, where user_list = UserProfile.objects.all()

```
    {% for user in user_list %}

        {{ user.user }}

        {{ user.posts }}

    {% endfor %}
```

However, I'm being greeted by this error page that says 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'post_set', or 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'post_set', depending on if I use user.user.posts or user.posts.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Post class you have defined the related name of your ForeignKey to User as `poster`. This means you can access all of a user's posts through `user.poster.all()`.

So your the `posts` method of your UserProfile class should be as follows:

```
def posts(self):
    return self.user.poster.all()
```

Comment: Hmm, I still get the same error if I use poster instead of post. It works using def posts(self): return self.user.poster.all(), so I guess I'll stick with that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In you example `User` does not have `post_set` attribute. If you want to get all posts for related User try this:

```
self.user.post.all()
```

Comment: It didn't work but it worked using 

def posts(self):
        return self.user.poster.all()

displaying  [<Post: Post object>] on the webpage, though I suppose I can then choose what parts to be displayed. Thanks!

Comment: @tryingtolearn You can edit my answer. So in future it will help other people.